# facebook infinite session key javascript

Tags: javascript, session, facebook, key, infinite

Looking to run through something very similar to (http://www.emcro.com/blog/2009/01/facebook-infinite-session-keys-no-more/) but using javascript instead. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You need offline_access permission from the user. See this:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

You can accomplish this with FBML/JavaScript, using the following code:

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="offline_access"></fb:login-button>
```